# Sorting incoming data

Tags: c#

I have the controller that sends me data from the database. Currently I am using `switch()` statement to do sorting logic and my code looks like this

```
switch (sort)
{
    case "title":
        books = books.OrderBy(b => b.Title);
        break;
    case "novelti_asc":
        books = books.OrderBy(b => b.Date);
        break;
    case "novelti_des":
        books = books.OrderByDescending(b => b.Date);
        break;
    default:
        books = books.OrderBy(b => b.Title);
        break;
}
```

This feels to me like an unnecessary code nesting. So I would like to know what is optimal solution for implementing data sorting.

Comment: Why it feels like unnecessary nesting? It looks clean to me.

Comment: @TimSchmelter because, in my opinion, my code will become less readable if I add, for example, 10 more sorting parameters as I will likely do in the future.

Comment: @JackFord - Use a `Dictionary<string, Func<IQueryable<Book>, IQueryable<Book>>>`.

Comment: what exactly feels unnecessary?

Comment: @JackFord: your current approach is the most efficient way to do this conditional sorting and it's also very readable and maintainable.

Comment: @TimSchmelter So it is exactly the way that an experienced engineer would approach it?

Comment: @JackFord: yes, we have used this approach (or if/else) often in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `Dictionary<string, Func<IQueryable<Book>, IQueryable<Book>>>` like this:

```
var orderBy = new Dictionary<string, Func<IQueryable<Book>, IQueryable<Book>>>()
{
    { "title", bs => bs.OrderBy(b => b.Title) },
    { "novelti_asc", bs => bs.OrderBy(b => b.Date) },
    { "novelti_des", bs => bs.OrderByDescending(b => b.Date) },
};
```

And then write:

```
books = orderBy[orderBy.ContainsKey(sort) ? sort : "title"](books);
```

The advantage here is that you can extend the functionality at run-time. You simply add more elements to the dictionary. You perhaps might give different users different options.

Comment: Does this really increase readability/maintainability? I don't think that you want to extend the dictionary at runtime. All sorting parameters must exist at compile time since the column must exist.

Comment: It increases flexibility and, arguably maintainability. Certainly not readability. I think the trade off is worth it. I particularly use this approach when injecting functionality when dynamically adding assemblies at run-time.

Comment: thats a neat solution is there a specific name for this so i can look it up and learn more about it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - "All sorting parameters must exist at compile time since the column must exist." - that's really not true. You could generate combinations of sorts at run-time. The type may contain dynamic properties. You could have a type with an internal dictionary of custom fields. There's all sorts of situations where you might modify things at run-time.

Comment: @Enigmativity: in your approach you can't generate combinations of sort, because you return `IQueryable<T>` not `IOrderedQueryable<T>`. Or you mean `bs => bs.OrderBy(b => b.Title).ThenBy(b => v.Date)`? That's possible with the `switch` too.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I don't disagree that it's possible with a `switch`, I just like the ability to modify this at run-time which switches don't do well.

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

- you need to separate field name and sorting type
- set sorting type by enum
- accepting fields as a string is also not very good, if you do something universal - maybe you will have to use reflection, if not - fields can also be set by enum
- a separate case for "title" can be omitted, since it matches the default one

Example:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

var booksList = new List<Book>()
{
    new Book(){Date = new DateOnly(2022, 10, 9), Title = "Book1"},
    new Book(){Date = new DateOnly(2022, 10, 10), Title = "Book2"},
    new Book(){Date = new DateOnly(2022, 10, 11), Title = "Book3"},
    new Book(){Date = new DateOnly(2022, 10, 12), Title = "Book4"},
}.AsQueryable();


var sort = new Sort { FieldName = "Title", SortType = SortType.Desc };

var result = booksList;

var properties = typeof(Book).GetProperties();
var property = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == sort.FieldName);

var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Book));
var propAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(paramExpr, property.Name);
var expr = Expression.Lambda(propAccess, paramExpr);


if (sort.SortType == SortType.Asc)
{
    var methodAsc = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "OrderBy" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
    var genericMethodAsc = methodAsc?.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Book), property.PropertyType);
    result = (IQueryable<Book>) genericMethodAsc?.Invoke(null, new object[] { booksList, expr})!;
}
else
{
    var methodDesc = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "OrderByDescending" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
    var genericMethodDesc = methodDesc?.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Book), property.PropertyType);
    result = (IQueryable<Book>) genericMethodDesc?.Invoke(null, new object[] { booksList, expr })!;
}

foreach (var book in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{book.Date} {book.Title}");
}


class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
}

enum SortType
{
    Asc,
    Desc
}

class Sort
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public SortType SortType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "you need to separate field name and sorting type" - the OP has already.

Comment: "set sorting type by enum" - how?

Comment: There are no fields being accepted as strings.

Comment: "a separate case for "title" can be omitted, since it matches the default one" - you would then have to somehow set "title" as default.

Comment: I'm possibly being overcritical, but I do think you need to provide some substance behind your statements to show what you really mean by them.

Comment: @Enigmativity "set sorting type by enum" - how?  - as it is done in [SortDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.sortdescription) struct

Comment: @nevermind - Yes, but Renat doesn't give that example or anything like it. It's the kind of of suggestion that requires the reader to already know the answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity You are being toxic. Why don't you give time to write an example after your own post and discuss me?

Comment: @RenatV - I admitted to possibly being overly critical, but I certainly wasn't being toxic.

Comment: The reflection approach would certainly be my very last resort. Why should i make my code almost unreadable, less efficient and more error-prone for no reason? This is just a bug source.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Again, I think it depends on the needs, versatility. If work is supposed to be done with only one table, then reflection is superfluous. Code above - only prototype, demo.